# How can I extract text after an element using Python and Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML code that I am trying to extract the text from:

```html
<fieldset>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">CNPJ:</label>011234560083
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">CIDADE:</label>TAUBATE
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">ESTADO:</label>SP
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">TOTAL BRUTO: </label>2.407,09
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">LIQ: </label>2.344,09
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

This code,

```python
print browse.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='grid-3-12 form-no-lbl']").text
```

returns just the first element: 011234560083

How can I read values for each label? Like "LIQ:" = 2.344,09

Answer (score 1):

If you have the luxury of having both Selenium and [lxml](https://lxml.de/) available, you could use Selenium for navigating to the desired page(s), and then using lxml to parse the HTML. For example,

```
import lxml.html as LH
# content = browser.page_source
content = '''\
<fieldset>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">CNPJ:</label>011234560083
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">CIDADE:</label>TAUBATE
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">ESTADO:</label>SP
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">TOTAL BRUTO: </label>2.407,09
    </div>
    <div class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl">
            <label class="form-lbl">LIQ: </label>2.344,09
    </div>
</fieldset>'''

root = LH.fromstring(content)
labels = root.xpath('//fieldset/div[@class="grid-3-12 form-no-lbl"]/label')
data = [[item.strip() for item in [elt.text, elt.tail]] for elt in labels]
```

yields

```
[['CNPJ:', '011234560083'],
 ['CIDADE:', 'TAUBATE'],
 ['ESTADO:', 'SP'],
 ['TOTAL BRUTO:', '2.407,09'],
 ['LIQ:', '2.344,09']]
```

Comment: Perfect, but sorry , how can i get the entire HTML from this:   {>>> elem = brf.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='grid-3-12 form-no-lbl']")
>>> print elem
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a513f6c7-ecf8-4ab4-82
45-208018507295", element="{b87c7a58-e899-4b01-a029-60ecb89d54b7}")>}

Comment: @Lara sure, use the `elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")`. (or use `innerHTML` if you don't need the current elements representation in the output).

Answer (score 1):

It seems really odd that your code doesn't work. I haven't run into a case quite like this. I think the code below should work. Basically I grab the text inside the `LABEL` and prepend it to the text you are already finding. The combination should get you the text you are looking for.

```
lines = browse.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.grid-3-12.form-no-lbl")
for line in lines
    print line.find_element_by_css_selector("label.form-lbl").text + line.text
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather common problem in Selenium. Just because *you cannot directly match the text nodes with `find_element_by_*` commands.*

In your case, I assume you know the `LIQ`, `ESTADO` etc labels beforehand and need to get a value by the label.

The idea would be to locate a `label` by text, move up the tree to the parent, get the text, split by `:` and get the last element which would correspond to the desired value:

```
label = "ESTADO"
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[starts-with(., '%s:')]/.." % label).text
print(text.split(":")[-1].strip())
```